# Regex match every number between

Tags: php, regex

I want to get everything  between og": and ,

```
$array  = og":EVERYTHING,"pt":"balbalbeb;

preg_replace('(?<=\:)(.*?)(?=\,)', '', $array);

$newarray = 'EVERTHING';
```

i tried this but not working

Comment: Could you paste a piece of the input ?

Comment: And why are you using `preg_replace` if you want to **match** ?

Comment: `(.*?)` does not only match a number, no idea what you are actually doing there.

Comment: please echo `$array_imghtml_2[1]` and provide us with the output

Comment: Please fix the input, this code is not valid and is not related to what you are trying to do (no number).

Comment: @Kikoop, this code will get you a parse error, please `var_dump()` the data you are using to avoid confusion.

Comment: Why do you call your variables `$array` and `$newarray` when they are not arrays? What does `$newarray` have to do with the code that precedes it?

Comment: It gets a bit confusing and it would be much better if you could provide the current output etc. But I think your problem is that you actually replace the matched pattern in your array. So it should look like:`og":,"pt":"balbalbeb;`

preg_match might be a better candidate. You could try something like `preg_match('(?<=\:)(.*?)(?=\,)', $array, $newarray)`, which should put the results to newarray. 
Also you currently match anything between a `:` and `,`. In your question you included og. Then your pattern should look like: `(?<=og"\:)(.*?)(?=\,)`